# Unable to open or read log files: FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, os.walk

This should be fairly simple, but I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to iterate over a list of files to find a specific phrase within the files, and then print the filename(s) that contain the phrase.

It reads the path fine, and adds the files to a list, then prints the list of files, but when I try to open each one to search for the phrase, I get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

```
import os 

FILENAMES = []
FILE_COUNT = 0
dir_path = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\Python Scripts\Log Parsing\Logs"


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    # print(files)

    for filename in files:
        FILENAMES.append(filename)
        FILE_COUNT += 1
        print(filename)
    print(FILE_COUNT)

for filename in FILENAMES:
    print(filename," contains the following string:\n")
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if ("their browser") in line:       # search for specific phrase within file
            print(line)
        else:
            pass
    print('\n')
    f.close()
```

> Below is the output:
>
> server.log_2022-07-05T16-47-42 server.log_2022-07-05T20-43-09
> server.log_2022-07-06T10-54-28 server.log_2022-07-06T14-16-51
> server.log_2022-07-06T15-12-06 server.log_2022-07-06T15-31-42
> server.log_2022-07-06T16-06-15 server.log_2022-07-06T16-34-07
> server.log_2022-07-06T17-00-03 server.log_2022-07-06T17-15-50
> server.log_2022-07-06T17-34-18 server.log_2022-07-06T17-48-16
> server.log_2022-07-07T08-08-16 272 server.log_2022-02-12T08-09-29
> contains the following string:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\me\Documents\Python Scripts\Log
> Parsing\Logs\logs_v4.py", line 19, in 
> f = open(filename, 'r') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'server.log_2022-02-12T08-09-29'

It's obviously reading the filenames. I don't understand FileNotFoundError.

Comment: `FILENAMES.append(filename)` You're appending just the bare filename, without the directory.  So when you try to open that file later, it looks in the current directory.

Comment: ... should probably be `FILENAMES.append(os.path.join(root, filename))`

Comment: Or just use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)...

Comment: Awesome guys! Thanks! Those tips solved it. I knew it was some dumb user mistake.